# How to implement anisotropic diffusion using java?

Tags: java, anisotropic-diffusion

I am working on an image processing project in java where we use anisotropic diffusion for scale space generation.

In the below equation, after finding the diffusion value.using the second equation, I do not know how to find the divergence of diffusivity and gradient.

[image]
[image]

Since I am getting the diffusivity as a float value. I do not know how to find the divergence of that.can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I coded a modest Java implementation of the Perona & Malik anisotropic diffusion, based on the ImgLib2 library. You can find it [here](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2-algorithm-gpl/blob/master/src/main/java/net/imglib2/algorithm/pde/PeronaMalikAnisotropicDiffusion.java).

You will have to import and learn how to use the [ImgLib2](http://fiji.sc/ImgLib2) library though. Here is [an example](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/net/imglib2/algorithm/pde/PeronaMalikAnisotropicDiffusionExample.java) using the anisotropic diffusion algorithm.

Otherwise, [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Anisotropic_Diffusion_2D.java) is a 2D only implementation, by Vladimir Pilny and Jiri Janacek, made for the [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/index.html) software.

And [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/anisotropic-diffusion.html) is another one for ImageJ as well, by Christopher Mei.

Best regards.

Comment: The third solution by Christopher Mei worked.Many thanks.